# How to use two-factor authentication at btc-e?

Tags: two-factor, btce

btc-e has a very confusing process of enabling 2-factor.
How should I use it?

[image]

Should I generate a one time password with a Yubikey?
Should I backup the private key / base32 ?

What does this auth process do?

(P.S. btc-e - you need to hire some better UX people)

Comment: what if you only have a mobile phone, not an android or iphone, how do you do it then ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it was easy to set up for me using an android phone ... just install the google auth, scan the code they give you on btc

new users should take a screen shot of the QR code and print it out and save in secure location.  You can't get back to that QR code, so save it from the beginning.

Here is a more general info on the topic:

http://cadince.com/3-ways-to-move-google-authenticator/

Answer (score 0):

At first I didn't find this on Google, but I just saw this on their blog:

> To protect your account from hacking you should:
>
> 1. Create a key in profile->security https://btc-e.com/profile#security/2fa
> 2. Scan the QR code using the Google Authenticator (or enter key to another application)
> 3. Confirm by entering the one-time password
>
> Following these simple steps you can turn a one-time password to log
>   into your account, withdrawals, or to change the security settings.
>
> Install Google Authenticator: Android:
>   https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.authenticator2
>   iOS: https://itunes.apple.com/ru/app/google-authenticator/id388497605

Comment: I still don't understand whether it can be used with a Yubikey, and if so how.

Comment: AFAIK Yubikey is its own thing, and unless it is explicitly supported it cannot be used.

Comment: @MeniRosenfeld - yeah, I think so too ... what a shame.